# Error with "mvn spring-boot:run", [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to use the command mvn spring-boot:run or when i try to use the command mvn clen install. But it's giving me this kind of error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>qualabs</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if i run the project using the main method in the application it's runnig perfectly.
I don't know if this a problem of dependencies

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: What java version is mvn using https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-invalid-target-release-17/

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following command to check which Java version is used by default on your computer:

```
java -version
```

If it differs from the 17 version, which you're trying to use in your project, you should update your JAVA_HOME variable.

You can use this command to list all available Java versions, installed on your computer:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Example output from my machine:

```
    17.0.2 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0.2" /Users/golovnya/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home
    11.0.14.1 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Users/golovnya/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.14.1/Contents/Home
```

Such command may be used for setting a specific Java version as the default one (17 in this example):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)
```